# Domain of Double Integrals

Tags: calculus

I'm working on this double integral:

$ \int_\mathcal{D} \sqrt{x^4+1} dA \; \; \text{At the domaine       } \mathcal{D} = \{(x, y) \; |\; 0 \leq y \leq 8 \; \text{ and }\; \sqrt[3]{y} \leq x \leq 2 \} $

My questions, how to calculate the domain. As far as I can understand (please correct me if wrong!), the integral bounds for y is simply 0 to 8:

$ \int_0^8  $

But how about the domain for x? What confuses me, is that there is BOTH a y-variable and x-variable in

$ 3\sqrt(y) \leq x \leq 2 $

Hope you can help me!

Comment: Yeah, so you have a double integral like $$\int_0^2 \int_{\sqrt[3]y}^{2} \sqrt{x^4+1} \ dxdy$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But how did you find/calculate the bounds? For example, what happens to the 8 in 0 <= y <= 8 ?

Comment: You're right—Tavish meant $$\int_0^8 \int_{\sqrt[3]y}^2 \sqrt{x^4+1} \,dx \,dy.$$

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at the graph of $x=y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and the restrictions $0\le y\le 8,y^{\frac{1}{3}}\le x\le 2$, we can easily see that the integral can be written as
$$\int_0^2 \int_0^{x^3}\sqrt{x^4+1}dydx=\int_0^2\sqrt{x^4+1}x^3dx=\dfrac{(x^4+1)^{\frac{3}{2}}}{6}\bigg|_0^2=\dfrac{17\sqrt{17}-1}{6}.$$
Notice that $y\in [0,8]$, since the value of $f(x)=x^3$ has image in $[0,8]$ when $x\in [0,2]$.

Using this formulation of the integral it becomes easier to solve because we can make the substitusion $u=x^4+1$, whose derivative is exactly the term $x^3$ multiplied by a constant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Its very useful for me. I can see that y^1/3 is 2 when y = 8. But don't get the idea behind, and I'm thinking "why not 0^1/3." Is there a theory/theorem I can study to understand this better? Thank you again for taking your time!

Comment: I simply wrote a $f(x)$ instead of a $g(y)$, seeing the function $x=y^{\frac{1}{3}}$ as $y=x^3$. Try to look at the area bounded by the function and by the resetrictions on your set $D$.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform this integral by switching the order of integration. The domain can also be described by $0 \leq x \leq 2$ and $0 \leq y \leq x^3$. Then,
$$I = \iint \sqrt{x^4+1 } \mbox{ dA} = \int_0 ^2 \int _0 ^{x^3}\sqrt{x^4+1 } \mbox{ dy dx}.$$
Evaluating the $y-$integral first gives
$$ I =  \int_0 ^2 x^3 \sqrt{x^4+1} \mbox{ dx} = \frac{1}{6}(x^4+1)^{3/2} |_0 ^2 = \frac{1}{6}(17\sqrt{17} - 1).$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's a great help for me! So, should you alway change the "order" of the domain, so the inequality with x is first, and y second?